# Calculating hex color codes in php?

Tags: php, hex

Starting with a value like "1B56E0" (dark blue color, used in .css files), is there any way to create the color codes for progressively darker or lighter shades of that color? Ideally the function would also accept the number of "steps" that should be generated.

You can see the values of colors [here](http://www.colorpicker.com/) but I can't figure out how the next "step" is calculated, sometimes there are letters, sometimes it's only numbers.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I's suggest converting the RGB color to the HSV color space and then turn up and down the V(value) or brightness part.

You can find a Hex to RGB algorithm here: [Convert Hex to RGB for imagegif function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881241/convert-hex-to-rgb-for-imagegif-function).

Look at this algorithm for conversion: [RGB to HSV in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773698/rgb-to-hsv-in-php).